# Develop windows phone 8 app after installing update 2 of Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I want to develop windows phone 8 app but I installed update 2 of visual studio 2013 which only develop windows phone 8.1 app.Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Please do not devote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely still create Windows Phone 8.0 projects with Visual Studio 2013.

When looking at the new project templates you want to look at Visual C#->Store Apps->Windows Phone Apps. From there scroll to the bottom, you want to choose from the Windows Phone Silverlight App templates. Choose any of them and you'll be prompted to target 8.0 or 8.1. Choose 8.0 and you should be good to go.